# How to publish ECW images to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, ecw

When I am going to publish mxd (containging image.ecw) to ArcGIS Server, the following error appears:

> Confiquration image.ecw. MapServer can not be started. Server Object
>   instance creation failed on machine.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have image server?

Answer (score 7):

See this [ESRI KB article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36261) on publishing ECWs to ArcGIS Server - it requires special (extra) licensing from ERDAS. This may be your issue.

Also, are you able to publish *any* map service?

Comment: You need the license. Asked for a quote last year and the license started a $3000+ for a 4-Core server up to 5K for a 16-Core...

Comment: What are the fastest and the most simple way to convert ECW to other format ? Thanks Geog

Answer (score 0):

You need ERDAS ECW for ArcGIS license to publish ECWs...

Comment: What are the fastest and the most simple way to convert ECW to other format ? Thanks Geog

Comment: use global mapper to convert

Comment: To what format ? who long sulde it take ?

Comment: I'v converted The ECW to Raster Catlog and it came out 65 GB - Heavy and not practical- what beter options i have ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert the ECW into a tile cache.  Use ArcMap Data Management Tools > Tile Cache > Manage Tile Cache tool.

If you have many ECW images, you can create a mosaic dataset of ECW images, then use the above tool to create the cache of all the ecw images.

Once a tile cache is built, ArcMap will read this as an image format.